# Локальная папка wwwroot в проекте backend. Как её получить во frontend'e?

Tags: c#, reactjs, frontend, backend

Есть проект backend'a написанный на c#. и Проект frontend'a на react.

Я хочу получить файлы из локальной папки на беке, чтобы отобразить документ(картинку, не особо важно). И суть в том, что фронт не видит эту папку разумеется, потому что она в другом проекте.

Как мне её подключить к фронту? Или каким-то особым образом указать у компонента в атрибуте src?

К примеру:

```
<iframe src="/~wwwroot/files/Акт№42.pdf" width="700" height="900"></iframe>
```

Не работает

Comment: Не обязательно в УРЛ указывать физически существующие папки. Ведь сервер (все равно на чем писан) может обрабатывать любые запросы к нему. Как то запросы с началом `http://files/<тут_любое>` отрабатывать следующим образом. Берем оставшуюся часть УРЛ (тут_любое)... Смотреть некую папку на наличие в ней `тут_любое` и если это `любое` есть - отправлять в ответе.

Comment: @ksa Мне не понятно. Мне надо получить вполне существующий документ, который находится по директории backend\wwwroot\files


Проект, аля на адресе https://localhost:8000 видит только то, что находится в frontend\public\

2 разных проекта.


Если я ввожу того, чего нет во front'e, но есть в back'e, то он мне ничего не выводит

Comment: Так если нечего не менять на беке - оно так и работает. А вот если дописать обработку запросов с УРЛ, которые начинаются на некое "ключевое слово" - сам бек может брать файлы откуда пожелает или откуда ему открыт доступ. У меня все на JS, сервер на Node.js и мои примеры тебе мало помогут. Тут главное понять суть "дополнительной" обработки запросов к серверу.